# How to recreate all fragments in ViewPager:

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have this problem, I have a `FragmentActivity` with a `ViewPager` and a `ViewPagerAdapter`.

In this ViewPager I have 3 `Fragments` that each of them contains a `TableLayout` that gets populated programmaticly using a `2dArrayList`.

on a click of a button in the `FragmentActivity` layout, I filter the data in the `2dArrayList` and basically need to recreate all 3 `Fragments` with the new dataset (run the `onCreateView` method in all of them).

So I create an `onClickListener` for this button:

```
 private class SlicerSelectedOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    private ODSharedSlicer slicer;

    public SlicerSelectedOnClickListener(ODSharedSlicer slicer) {
        super();
        this.slicer = slicer;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String slicerValue = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG,"Slicer value: "+ slicerValue +" chosen");
        application.currentReport.getODSharedSlicers().get(0).getSharedSlicerSelectedMemebers().add(slicerValue);

        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) ((Button) v).getParent();

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) 
        {
            if ((parent.getChildAt(i) != v) && (parent.getChildAt(i) instanceof ToggleButton))
            {
                ((ToggleButton) parent.getChildAt(i)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }

        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have a `mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`
As suggested here:

[How to recreate fragment with viewpager intentionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15179086/how-to-recreate-fragment-with-viewpager-intentionally)

at the end of this method, So I expect the adapter to recreate all the `Fragment`s, but the `onCreateView` from any of the fragments never runs.

Can any one suggest what am I doing wrong.
any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you override the `getItemPosition()` method in the adapter to return `POSITION_NONE`?

Comment: No, I didn't. should I do that to use the notifyDataSetChanged() method in ViewPager?

Comment: It wouldn't take you much to test it:)

Comment: @Luksprog, I tried it but for some reason POSITION_NONE can't resolve to a variable. in which class does this constant sits? I can't find it?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#POSITION_NONE

Comment: @Luksprog, stupid me. Don't know how I missed it. checking right now.

Comment: @Luksprog, I have added the getItemPosition() method with return POSITION_NONE. like describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263291/viewpager-pageradapter-not-updating-the-view/7287121#7287121 but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: can you try with mViewPager.setApdater(mPagerAdapter)

Comment: I made a mistake in placing the getItemPosition as part of the FragmentActivity and not as part of the adapter. As soon as I changed that it works as expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As been suggested here by @Luksprog, changing my adapter class to this:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
private List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}  
}
```

Fixed my issue.

what I did was to add this method:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

Comment: I also needed to change `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` for this to work

Answer (score 24):

for those who still face the same problem which I faced the same  problem when I have `ViewPager` with seven fragment. the default for these fragments to load the English content from the service but the problem here that I want to change the language from settings activity and after finish settings activity I want `ViewPager` in main activity to refresh the fragment to match the language selection from the user and load the Arabic content if user choose Arabic here what I did to work from the first trr :D

**1. you must use FragmentStatePagerAdapter* .**

2. mainActivity I overrided the `onResume` and did the following

   ```
    if (!(mPagerAdapter == null)) {

            mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
   ```
3. I ovveride the `getItemPosition()` in `mPagerAdapter` and make it return POSITION_NONE.

   ```
    @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

            return POSITION_NONE;
        }
   ```

works like charm

Comment: I m using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and  from a Button OnclickListener() I have Called `mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` and also Overriding ..But no effect on ViewPager.its not recreating

Comment: did you override @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {

        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

Comment: yes i did. `notifyDataSetChanged();` is still not recreating the fragments again

Comment: hi hemant,  if you still have the problem you can make the adapter global object  and then when change call adapter.notifydatasetchanged(); the adapter should be global to to update  adapter give this a try

Comment: i just want to change the backgrounds of the fragments by recreating it but i did it using a array of view  and changing background one by one of each fragment . and my adapter is already global ..so

Comment: I am using exactly this solution but it is working only for Nougat and not for all previous versions. What's the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

getActivity.recreate() will recreate activity hence all fragments

Answer (score 0):

on @Emil-adz solution we can go little ahead because we got fragment listy in  my case called _fragments we can return fragment position like this:

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    /** check if object is fragment class */
    if (object.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Fragment.class)) {
        /** cast object to fragment */
        Fragment customFragment = (Fragment)object;
        /** return fragment position from our list */
        return _fragments.indexOf(customFragment);
    } else {
        /** else re-create */
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```