# Update ViewPager's Fragments from another class:

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

Following this question:

[How to recreate all fragments in ViewPager:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671695/how-to-recreate-all-fragments-in-viewpager)

I have those classes:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter 
{
private List<Fragment> fragments;

/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}  
}
```

and a `FragmentActivity`:

```
 public class TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  
 ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener 
 {
    static final String TAG = TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private TabHost mTabHost;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private HashMap<String, TabInfo> mapTabInfo = new HashMap<String,      TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity.TabInfo>();
    public ViewPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;
    .....
```

Now in this `FragmentActivity` I have this listener:

```
  private class SlicerSelectedOnClickListener implements OnClickListener 
{
    private ODSharedSlicer slicer;
    private int slicerIndex;

    public SlicerSelectedOnClickListener(ODSharedSlicer slicer, int slicerIntex)
    {
        super();
        this.slicer = slicer;
        this.slicerIndex = slicerIntex;
    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        slicerOnClickConfiguration(slicerIndex, v);
        mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
    ....
```

And this works great `notifyDataSetChanged()` is getting called and the ViewPager's Fragments are getting recreated as I want.

**The Problem:** When I try to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the adapter from another class (In my case it's a class that responsible to parse data that is received from the server) the fragments remain unchanged.

I tried to do this: I created those methods in my `FragmentActivity` class (the one with the `ViewPager`):

```
 public void NotifyTabActivityViewPagerAdapter()
{
    mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public ViewPagerAdapter getTabActivityViewPagerAdapter()
{
    return mPagerAdapter;
}

public ViewPager getTabActivityViewPager()
{
    return mViewPager;
}
```

And tried the following from the second class:

```
((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)currentActivity).NotifyTabActivityViewPagerAdapter();
```

Or:

```
((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)currentActivity).getTabActivityViewPager().setAdapter(((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)currentActivity).getTabActivityViewPagerAdapter());
```

But non of this works. Strangely when I run this:

```
((TabsViewPagerFragmentActivity)currentActivity).getTabActivityViewPager().setAdapter(null);
```

The fragments do get removed, But I can't recreate the new set of fragments with the new data received from server side.

What am I missing here? How should I recreate all the fragment in this `FragmentActivity` from another class?

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really like 7 questions in there. But I understand the main question to be updating or sending data to a `FragmentActivity` associated with a `ViewPager` from some other class. I don't know this other classes relationship to the `FragmentActivity` or `ViewPager` but there are 2 ways I know of that could handle updating or transfering information the way you want

(1) an [interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

If the class you're referring to is another `Fragment` and loaded in the same `ViewPager` the way you would update the data (or call a method) in another `Fragment` or `FragmentActivity` is with an interface. You can scroll to the bottom of that link for some sample code but basicly you create a bridge between the `Fragment` and the activity that contains the `ViewPager` (i.e. the fragment's host activity). You then create a "listener" that looks for some change in the `Fragment`, upon which it passes some information to the hoast activity. The host activity then calls a public method within the second `Fragment` you need to update. Only tricky part here is to remember to initialize your interface "listener"within your `Fragment`'s `onAttach` method or it won't work.

(2) an intent

If  you're dealing with two seperate activities just use an `Intent`. Pass an intent to the `FragmentActivity` you're looking for and override `onNewIntent(Intent i)` to perform whatever function you want within the recieving class.

Hope that helps - I'd need more specificy to answer futher because there's a lot of sub-questions in there.

Comment: Actually this second class is a helper class, and is not extending Fragment or Activity. And there is only one question here: "How should I recreate all the fragment in this FragmentActivity from another class?" the flow goes like this: I have a custom View in my FragmentActivity, the custom view pops a popup, choosing an option from this pop up starts an AsyncTask that gets data from the server, Next I have a helper class (a simple class) that parses this data, and when it finishes I would like to run .notifyDataSetChanged(); from this class or some other way as I did in the listener.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that from before. If you're class is just implementing `AsyncTack` why can't you just set up a callback between that class and its `onPostExecute` method?

Comment: Because in onPostExecute I call a method "ResponseHandler.ParseRecievedData(String data)", where "ResponseHandler" is a simple java class where I store all my methods that deal with AsyncTask web requests. I want to keep this separation. but I can't undestand how to Call NotifyDataSetChanged() from the "ResponseHandler" class. Does it has to do some thing with the Activity/Application context?

Comment: Just add another method in your `onPostExecute` that calls it once your response is parsed. And yes, it has to do with the Context - [see this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119305/android-how-to-run-asynctask-from-different-class-file) on how to use Context when running AsncTask from a seperate class

Comment: Calling NotifyDataSetChanged does work from the onPostExecute, but for some reason not from my helper class to which I pass my activity. weird. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: That is weird. If you figure out why that is please add it to the post.

Comment: I will do that, if I will figure out the source of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the case and I think that you should make sure that `NotifyTabActivityViewPagerAdapter` is running at onPostExecute, but I had a project where 
`notifyDataSetChange` didn't work and the fragment remained empty.
To solve it, I override the getItemPosition in the adapter as follows:

```
 @Override
 public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
  return POSITION_NONE;
 }
```

By returning `POSITION_NONE` you make sure that the adapter refresh all its data.

Comment: You can see from the first question that I posted a link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671695/how-to-recreate-all-fragments-in-viewpager I already added this method to the adapter.