# Refreshing the content on a view pager's fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have an activity , which holds two fragments via view pager.
I have an arraylist displayed on fragment A, and a list view of items in fragment B. When I check some of these items and click on a button they are passed to the array list of fragment A and should be displayed first.

The data does pass to fragment A as it is supposed to. 
The problem is that it doesn't display the refreshed array list.

I tried making the ViewPager member static, and then pass it to fragment A every time I click that button in fragment B to pass the content to fragment A. 
Then in fragment A I do notifyDataSetChanged() on that adapter member.
It still doesn't work though.

```
public class PagerActivity extends FragmentActivity implements  MainFragment.AddToHistoryInterface
{
    static ViewPagerAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
{
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_pager );

    ViewPager viewPager = ( ViewPager ) findViewById( R.id.viewPager );
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter( getSupportFragmentManager() );
    viewPager.setAdapter( adapter );
}


public static void removeFromB( List<Password> listFromB )
{
    MainFragment.fromBtoA( listFromB, adapter );
}
```

Then, in fragment A:
....
...

```
public static void fromHistoryToMain( List<Password> listBackToMain, ViewPagerAdapter adapter )
    {
        passwordsList.addAll( 0, listBackToMain );
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Your answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671695/how-to-recreate-all-fragments-in-viewpager

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. I tried doing exactly as it stated in the accepted answer there.
Thank you though for referring me to that link

Comment: you are using wrong adapter ... you don't wana update adapter which generates pages ... but adapter used to display data on one page .... anyway nice one content provider + loaders api would do the thing