# ViewPager Fragments are not recreated after FragmentTransaction.replace() followed by back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle

I am trying to implement saving and restoring state, but I am running into problems when replacing the main `Fragment` with a `PreferenceFragment` and then hitting the back button. My main `Fragment` consists of a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter` with 3 `Fragments` to swipe through. None of the `Fragment.onCreateView()` callbacks for my 3 `Fragment`s are invoked after hitting the back button. I have tried all the solutions I have come over here on SO, but I have not been able to resolve the issue.

Another possibly important thing to note is that the data for my 3 `ViewPager` `Fragment`s are stored in separate classes which are instanced and accessible through the `Activity`. The 3 `Fragment`s all contain `RecyclerView`s for listing a fair amount of data. This is done for cleanliness, but also so that these data persist in the `Activity`. This is *probably* not an issue, since it works fine when starting the app, but also since the main issue is that my `Fragments` are not recreated.

**Unexpected behavior:**

On application creation, everything works fine, but when I replace my main `Fragment` (containing a `ViewPager` with a `FragmentPagerAdapter`) with another one and then pressing the back button, the `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager` are not recreated. The `onCreateView()` of my main `Fragment` *is* called.

**Questions:**

What am I missing? Is there some other callbacks that should be created? Where and how should I recreate the `Fragments`?

**What have I tried:**

1. Changed the `FragmentAdapter` in use, but I should really use `getSupportFragmentManager()` as was the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600156/fragment-in-viewpager-not-restored-after-popbackstack).

**EDIT: Use of erroneous `FragmentManager` actually *was* the source of my troubles. See my answer below.**

2. Add
   `@Override public int getItemPosition(Object object) {return POSITION_NONE;}` to the `FragmentPagerAdapter`, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16671695/how-to-recreate-all-fragments-in-viewpager).
3. Change from `FragmentPagerAdapter` to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` which should not matter here, as far as I understand. The internals of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` actually keeps the `Fragments`, but they are not rendered anew.
4. Add the main `Fragment` back using a `FragmentTransaction` when its `onCreateView()` is called and in several of the other callbacks of that `Fragment`, see `MMMainFragment` below.
5. Various other things.

#### My MainFragment class with corresponding XML layout

```
public class MMMainFragment extends Fragment
{
    private MMViewPager mMMViewPager = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Note that this method IS called when the back button is pressed.
        // I have tried setting the content back to this instance in several places.

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mm_main_fragment, container, false);

        // Setup ViewPager.
        mMMViewPager = (MMViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.mm_pager);
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mm_tablayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mMMViewPager);

        return view;
    }

    public MMViewPager getMMViewPager()
    {
        return mMMViewPager;
    }
}
```

#### mm_main_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/mm_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable" />

    <com.mycompany.myapp.gui.mmpager.MMViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mm_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Then, in `Activity.onCreate()` i simply do:

```
// Insert Main Fragment.
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.mm_content_frame, new MMMainFragment())
        .commit();
```

where `mm_content_frame` is a `FrameLayout` where I replace and remove `Fragment`s. Then, when a button to view the preferences are pushed, I run the following snippet below in the `Activity`. I add this `Fragment` to the backstack to be able to use the back button.

```
public void showSettingsFragment()
{
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.mm_drawer_settings));
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mm_content_frame, new MMPreferencesFragment(), FragmentConstants.SETTINGS_FRAGMENT_TAG)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

#### The MMViewPager clas:

```
public class MMViewPager extends ViewPager
{
    private MMActivity mMMActivity;
    private MMPagerAdapter mMMPagerAdapter;

    public MMViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        mMMActivity = (MMActivity) context;
        mMMPagerAdapter = new MMPagerAdapter(mMMActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), mMMActivity);

        this.setOffscreenPageLimit(PagerConstants.OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT);
        this.setAdapter(mMMMPagerAdapter);
        this.setCurrentItem(PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES);
    }
}
```

#### The MMPagerAdapter class, currently a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public class MMPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter
{
    private MMActivity mMMActivity;

    public MMPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, MMActivity mmActivity)
    {
        super(fragmentManager);
        mMMActivity = mmActivity;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES:
                return new FilteredRecipesFragment();

            case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES:
                return new SelectedRecipesFragment();

            case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST:
                return new ShoppingListFragment();

            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return PagerConstants.NUMBER_OF_PAGES; // 3
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
    {
        switch (position)
        {
            case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES:
                return mMMActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.mm_title_recipe_filter_fragment);

            case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES:
                return mMMActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.mm_title_selected_recipes_fragment);

            case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST:
                return mMMActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.mm_title_shopping_list_fragment);

            default:
                return "Tab";
        }
    }
}
```

#### For reference, here is also the main layout of the `Activity`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mm_drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Source: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html -->
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Source: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mm_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            style="@style/MMActionBar"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <!-- The FrameLayout where I replace Fragments -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/mm_content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/mm_toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mm_drawer_listview"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingStart="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="@color/mm_white" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After struggling with this for a few days I realized that the problem actually *was* that I passed the wrong `FragmentManager` to the `ViewPager`. It is indeed the `FragmentManager` returned by `Fragment.getChildFragmentManager()` that should be used. This makes sense, since it is the `Fragment` itself that stores the state of the child `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager`. I am not sure why I couldn't make that work before, but now the LifeCycle of the app works fine with the following setup in my main `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mm_main_fragment, container, false);

    mMMActivity = (MMActivity) container.getContext();
    mMMActivity.getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.mm_toolbar_title_main_fragment));

    // Setup ViewPager.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.mm_pager);
    mAdapter = new MMPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), mMMActivity); // <-- This is the key
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(PagerConstants.OFFSCREEN_PAGE_LIMIT);
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES);

    // Setup TabLayout.
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mm_tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    return view;
}
```

This was also the solution of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16683004/1139324). As a side note, I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15261142/1139324) to get the `Fragment`s in my `ViewPager` and it works just fine with the LifeCycle.

#### Test Application:

In the research of this issue I created a test application for this. The ones interested can clone it from [here](https://github.com/oysteinmyrmo/viewpagerlifecycletest). It has ugly colors.

Comment: getChildFragmentManager only works for API 17 and above. If I'm supporting API 16 as well, is there alternative to the solution?

Comment: Are you importing the Fragment and the ViewPager from `android.support.v4.app`?

Comment: The View Pager is from `android.support.v4.app`, but the fragment is normal Fragment.

Comment: Change that to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and you should be good to go. If you are to support older versions of Android you have to use the support libraries.

Comment: Ya, that's the way. Unfortunately the fragment we have is inherited from a base fragment that is used by others. To make that change, massive code change :(

Comment: Thanks this has taken my 2 hours.

Comment: Ohh god, you are my savior :D

Answer (score 0):

As far as, I understand you have solved your problem. I have faced a quite similar issue in the past. Maybe this help others trying something similar.

The thing that helped me in order to retain my fragment state was to replace the

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position)
{
    switch (position)
    {
        case PagerConstants.PAGE_FILTER_RECIPES:
            return new FilteredRecipesFragment();

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SELECTED_RECIPES:
            return new SelectedRecipesFragment();

        case PagerConstants.PAGE_SHOPPING_LIST:
            return new ShoppingListFragment();

        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

method of my adapter.

I change the `Adapter` so as to keep a `HashMap` of `Fragment`. This way the fragments are created once and then retrieved from the HashMap. Depending on your structure you can use an `ArrayList` instead of the HashMap.

This is done in an efficient and "smart" way of implementing `getItemPosition(Object object)` to `return POSITION_NONE;` or the proper position of the item.

I don't really remember if I had the `getChildFragmentManager` in the adapter or not.

I guess that I could dig into my filesystem if you need further information :)

Comment: Yes, that is another issue; how to get `Fragment`s that are currently stored in the `ViewPager`. Your solution is workable as far as I know. I use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager/15261142#15261142) solution to solve this myself.